# How to create Mysql table from array values in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to create a database table from the CSV header.
here is my code.

```
//give a path of file
$path =  $request->file->getRealPath();
//gives csv header and store in array
$store =  ((((Excel::load($path))->all())->first())->keys())->toArray(); 
return dd(array_values ($store));
```

Output:

```
array:2 [▼
    0 => "title"
    1 => "description"
]
```

I want to create a table with the column name (title, description) How?

thanks.

Comment: I figured out.  Following code will get header from CSV or EXCEL file and create SQL table from those headers.

                $path =  $request->file->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path)->first()->keys()->toArray();
            
                Schema::connection('mysql')->create('aas', function($table) use($data) {
                $table->increments('id');
                for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++)
                $table->string($data[$i]);
                
                });

                return dd(array_values ($data));

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out.  Following code will get header from CSV or EXCEL file and create SQL table from those headers.

```
            $path =  $request->file->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path)->first()->keys()->toArray();

            Schema::connection('mysql')->create('aas', function($table) use($data) {
            $table->increments('id');
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++)
            $table->string($data[$i]);

            });

            return dd(array_values ($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad idea. But if you really need it, you can do something like this:

```
$data = Excel::load($path)->first()->keys()->toArray();

\Schema::connection('mysql')->create('newTable', function($table) use($data) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string($data[0]);
    $table->string($data[1]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alexye. this is useful.

But, is there any way to create table from csv or excel header in laravel?

Comment: @sdsfdesf the code above will use title and description from your example above. If these are keys which are literally `title` and `description`, please show the result of `dd(Excel::load($path)->first()->toArray())`

Comment: array:2 [▼
  0 => "title"
  1 => "description"
]

this response I am getting.

Comment: This " title and description " is just an example.  Actually, I have a lot of CSV file which has around 50 columns. So, when I upload this file to the server, at the same time it should create SQL table in the database from the header.